# How to Select All cells If I click the one cell in GridTable?

Tags: wpf

**Have a nice day**

I am using the **WPF** platform, I have a one Grid and in the Grid 5 columns(**GridTextColumn**) and 10 Records are there,My question is if i click or select the one cell in the whole Grid i need to automatically all Cell is selected,Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please use real WPF classes names. Do you mean `DataGrid` and `DataGridTextColumn`?

Comment: Also what do you mean `all Cell is selected`? I don't understand what do you want, describe desired behavior better.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great site to search information about WPF classes and their members - **MSDN**. If you take a look at `DataGrid` class you will note that it has the `SelectAllCells` method. Use it to complete your task.